# Intent filter icon not getting picked - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, icons, intentfilter

**My Requirement:** If another app calls my intent, I want to pass a different icon than my application icon to show up on their app selection dialog box.

**My solution:**
I have defined an icon for my intent filter as below in my AndroidMainfest file

```
<intent-filter android:icon="@mipmap/intent_launcher"
                android:label="intent label icon">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="abc"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

and I have a different icon set for my application:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.myapplication"
        >
```

**My problem:**
When testing using a 2nd app I am able to invoke this intent and I am getting the label that I have defined , however the intent call is still picking up the application icon and not the one I have defined for the intent filter.

Am I missing something? Or this is not feasible at all.

I have tried the things described above.